# Is this a good IF block?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

Are these comparisons always safe from creating a NullPointer Exception ?

```
if( myObject == null || myObject.someMethod() == someValue )
{
    if( myObject == null && myObject.getAlwaysTrue() )
       {

       }
}
```

Is there some directional precedence in java for condition evaluation, apart from short circuiting ?

**UPDATE:** I Know `myObject.anything()` will throw a NullPointer. Its just that I have come across such code by other programmers, and I  want to know if there's a safe way of squeezing multiple checks along with a null check in a single condition. I'm looking for a good rule to stick to.

Comment: Precedence, always left to right (unless you have something in brackets).

Comment: Look into using an IDE. The nicer ones will flag this kind of unsafe code for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this line is not safe:

```
if( myObject == null && myObject.getAlwaysTrue() )
```

If you know that `myObject` is null then you shouldn't try to dereference it. If however you wrote this:

```
if( myObject != null && myObject.getAlwaysTrue() )
```

Then it would be safe. This is because `&&` (and `||` for that matter) has [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). If you write `a && b` and the expression `a` evaluates to false, then the expression `b` is not evaluated so it will not throw an exception. The left operand is always evaluated first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This pattern:  `!= null` in left with rest of `&&` checks OR `== null` in the left with rest of `||` checks. But this will not work with mixed `&&` and `||` .

Answer (score 3):

Why not separate out the gating issue?

```
if (myObject != null) {
    if ((myObject.someMethod() == someValue) && myObject.getAlwaysTrue()) {

    }
}
```

Comment: +1 things are really very simple, but we just avoid thinking towards best

Comment: @Nandkumar If it's not simple, I can't understand it an hour later ;)

Comment: Working from the code OP gave, this rephrasing is not an equal formulation. We can rephrase thus to get into the inner scope: (a OR b) AND (a AND c) = (a AND c) OR (a AND b AND c) where "a" is the check for null, "b" is the check for someValue and "c" is .getAlwaysTrue(). Your formulation is ((NOT a) AND b AND c) for the innermost scope, which is not the same.

Comment: @G.Bach Correct, nor would an equivalent formulation work, as the accepted answer states. Barring reading the OP's mind, I aimed at something more-likely to be the original intent. Who knows.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah, the code he posted doesn't make much sense in the first place; maybe I was nitpicking a little too much.

Answer (score 2):

```
if( myObject == null && myObject.getAlwaysTrue() )
```

This will cause you a `NullPointerException` when `myObject` is `null`

Answer (score 1):

If the `myObject` is `null`, `myObject.getAlwaysTrue()` in the second `if` statement will always result in `NullPointerException`.

In the case of `||` the `if` expression evaluates the boolean expressions until it finds the first one that's `true`.

With `&&` the `if` expression evaluates the boolean expressions until it finds the first one that's `false`.

So in your case when `myObject` is `null`, you'll get the following evaluations:

First `if`:

```
myObject == null -> true
```

Second `if`:

```
myObject == null -> true
myObject.getAlwaysTrue() -> NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

Wherever I can, I strive for less indentantion and complex "ifology". In your case I'd just write

```
if (myObject == null) return;
... go on knowing that myObject is not null...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not :

```
if( myObject == null && myObject.getAlwaysTrue() )
```

`&&` will check both conditions, `myObject.getAlwaysTrue()` will throw NullPointerException if myObject is null.

Comment: You might like to explain why ;)

Comment: You and I can see that, but it's obvious from the post, the OP doesn't

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas you've earned a cookie for the mind-compilation work :).